# Keep only the hours for which the value have not changed within the hour R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, time-series, identify

I have a timeseries dataset with 'n' number of columns. In the dataset, I would like to filter and remove the hours for which the value in a column changed within the hour. In other words, I want to keep the hours that has unchanged value.

Some info about the data:

- 1-minute data with date in POSCIXT format (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)
- The data is recorded for every 5 minutes, so for the time, for which the data is not recorded is filled with NA

  ```
  data1<- structure(list(PDT = structure(c(1668927600, 1668927660, 
     1668927720, 
    1668927780, 1668927840, 1668927900, 1668927960, 1668928020, 1668928080, 
    1668928140, 1668928200, 1668928260, 1668928320, 1668928380, 1668928440, 
    1668928500, 1668928560, 1668928620, 1668928680, 1668928740, 1668928800, 
    1668928860, 1668928920, 1668928980, 1668929040, 1668929100, 1668929160, 
    1668929220, 1668929280, 1668929340, 1668929400, 1668929460, 1668929520, 
    1668929580, 1668929640, 1668929700, 1668929760, 1668929820, 1668929880, 
    1668929940, 1668930000, 1668930060, 1668930120, 1668930180, 1668930240, 
    1668930300, 1668932640, 1668932700, 1668932760, 1668932820, 1668932880, 
    1668932940, 1668933000, 1668933060, 1668933120, 1668933180, 1668933240, 
    1668933300, 1668933360, 1668933720, 1668933780, 1668933840, 1668933900, 
    1668933960, 1668934020, 1668934080, 1668934140, 1668934200, 1668934260, 
    1668934320, 1668934380, 1668934440, 1668934500, 1668934560, 1668934620, 
    1668934680, 1668934740, 1668934800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), Date = structure(c(1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 
    1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400, 1668902400), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), DayOfWeek = c("Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
    "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday"), 
        Month = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
        11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
        11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
        11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
        11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
        11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), Day = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
        20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
        20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
        20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
        20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
        20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), Hour_hr = c(7, 
        7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
        7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
        7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
        8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
        9), Minute = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
        13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
        28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
        43, 44, 45, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
        36, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 
        56, 57, 58, 59, 0), ColA = c(NA, NA, NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.5, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.5, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.5, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        65.7, NA, NA)), row.names = 3041:3118, class = "data.frame")
  ```

Expected output:

In the above example, I want to exclude hour 8 from my dataset, as the value in ColA is not constant.

I have a feeling that `group_by()` and `filter()` from dplyr might do the job, but I am not sure about the function to find the unchanged values within an hour.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your expected output? It's not entirely clear to me

Comment: Hi @JuanC, In the above example, I don't want to exclude hour 0 from the time series data, as the value in ColA changed from 66 to 67. If the value in ColA remains the same for hour 0, I would like to keep the hour in my time series data.

Comment: Could you please use  `dput()`  to include some sample data and make this question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for others?

Comment: hey @Karthik, you told me you don't want to exclude (you want to keep) data when the value changes and you want to keep it when it doesn't change. Which of both are you looking for? Do you want to keep the whole series when one of the options happen? That's why we use reproducible examples, because you can leave a lot to the imagination

Comment: Hi @JuanC, thanks. I have added a reproducible example. Yes, I want to keep the whole time series data and just want to exclude the hours for which the value is not constant throughout the hour. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it:

```
data1 %>% group_by(Hour_hr)  %>% filter(n_distinct(ColA) < 3)
```

Checking results:

```
count(data1, Hour_hr)

  Hour_hr     n
    <dbl> <int>
1       7    46
2       9     1
```

This will keep colA if there's only one numerical value or no numerical values (NA), keeping hour 7 and 9.

Equivalently you could do:

```
data1 %>% group_by(Hour_hr)  %>% filter(n_distinct(ColA, na.rm = T) < 2)
```

Comment: Thanks :) Really appreciate your prompt response. It worked

Comment: Nice, I'm glad it did!

Comment: do the numbers 3, and 2 in your answer correspond to the no.of hours?

Comment: Nope, it's the number of possible different values of ColA within an hour. So in the first answer it accepts NA and one extra value, in the second it ignores NAs, so it  accepts only one unique value for ColA.  I'm not using `n_distinct(ColA, na.rm = T) == 1` because that leaves behind the hour 9, because there's no values